# Remove media controller gradient line

Tags: android, controller, line, media

I am doing an app that contains video player. There were a lot of issues related to it. However i have managed to solved them. I have a custom video view and custom media controller, but the video is not working in a separate activity but in a fragment.

When media player is working in landscape mode there is a thin black gradient line(i have done some padding to position it right). Here it is - http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/533/7351533I.png . I think that the black line comes from the media player control and i need to override the reference
https://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/media_controller.xml?r=44

```
 <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark" />
```

How this line could be accessed using reflection or how could i tell the android to override its internal used resource with my xml implementation?

Comment: Does anybody know how this line could be removed, interchanging the used xml (which contains the defined gradient line - divider_horizontal_dark) or from the code using reflection (which field should be runtime modified)?